# How to send many logs files inside container in k8s cluster using filebeat

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I will try to understand me. In my k8s cluster i have container which write many log files and this logs isn't container logs. For example in my container i have following log files:

`System.log, Trace.log, Da.log and other`

Before k8s i had used following configuration with :

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /opt/docker/container/volumes/logs/Da.log
```

And my question is how to update this configuration for k8s. I suppose that i would use volume mounts for filebeat but i don't know how is it works.

Comment: There would be so much to say about this topic... It would be nice to have a description of the whole environment. Anyway, to answer you, you will find everything here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-kubernetes.html

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question. In my app, i used logback.xml for logging and I edit this file for redirects to stdout and stderr. Config this like:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDERR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.err</target>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <target>System.out</target>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>DEBUG</level>
      <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>TRACE</level>
      <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>WARN</level>
      <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>ERROR</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDERR" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```